# How to calculate the sum of counts and add the number for each corresponding element in next column

Tags: excel, vba

I need to calculate the sum of counts and add the number for each corresponding element in next column. I don't know how I will do it. But it is possible to use vba code or excel formula to do it.

```
Title   Nbr
Oui 
Oui 
Oui 
Oui 
Non 
Non 
Non 
Non 
Non 
Yesi    
Yesi    
Yesi    
Gold    
Gold
```

**Expected result**

```
Title   Nbr
Oui      4
Oui      4
Oui      4
Oui      4
Non      5
Non      5
Non      5
Non      5
Non      5
Yesi     3
Yesi     3
Yesi     3
Gold     2
Gold     2
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Assume that your 'title' in 'A' Column then type the following formula in 'Nbr' in 'B' Column: `=COUNTIF($A$1:$A$14,A1)` and copy to your range.